# return str.replace(/\n\r?/g, "<br />") is not working, when I render JSON data to html element

Tags: json, line-breaks

I have JSON file like this below, inside `data.json`.

```
{
   "usfood":[
      {
         "fruits":"This is apple.\\nWe harvest every Spring."
      }
   ],
   "ukfood":[
      {
         "fruits":"This is melon.\\nWe harvest every Winter."
      }
   ]
}
```

I have HTML like this below, inside `index.php`.

`<p id="food_description"></p>`

I have jQuery code like this below, inside `<script>` tag of `index.php` .

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
 $.getJSON("data.json",function(data) {
   $('#food_description').html(replaceBreak(data['usfood'][0].usfood));
 })
});

function replaceBreak(str){
return str.replace(/\n\r?/g, "<br />");
}
```

Result:
The html element in the browser shows the original string

`This is apple.\\nWe harvest every Spring.`

I am guessing, the issue is the `replaceBreak` function.
How can I improve my code to successfully replace `\\n` with `<br />` ?
At the same time, it might be the order of codes.

I also tried `return str.replace("\n", "<br />");` `return str.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use booth string

```
return str.replace("\\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Comment: Are you checking if your string really contains your chars?

Comment: what do you mean?? I want to render JSON data to specific html element.

Comment: Try to print your str

Comment: To where? and what do you mean 'print'? Do you mean 'console.log()'?

Comment: Yes if you can... print in which way you want, the important things is to check if the characters that you are repleacing are inside the string

Comment: I did `function replaceBreak(str){ console.log(str.replace(/\n\r?/g, "<br />"))
return str.replace(/\n\r?/g, "<br />");
}` and this is the result I got `This is apple.\\nWe harvest every Spring.` **Maybe the code inside the function replaceBreak is the issue**

Comment: I've found the soluction, please see my answer edited

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help. Fortunately, it did work for one JSON data value. This does not work for my JSON file which has two `\\n`. For example, `"This is apple.\\nWe harvest every Spring.\\nThis is very nice."`

Comment: So the problem isn’t in repleace statemnt... now your console.log what are showing?

Comment: I just updated my comment! Did you see it??? Also, the `console.log()` shows me `This is apple.<br />We harvest every Spring.` So, this works fine. But when I have more than one `\\n`, it shows like the following `This is apple.<br />We harvest every Spring.\\nThis is very nice.`

Comment: Can you repost it?

Comment: repost of my comment===>>>>>I just updated my comment! Did you see it??? Also, the console.log() shows me `This is apple.<br />We harvest every Spring.` So, this works fine. But when I have more than one `\\n`, it shows like the following `This is apple.<br />We harvest every Spring.\\nThis is very nice.`

Comment: Yes sorry now i'm able to see that

Comment: So can you update your question? the issue isn't on the argument on the replate function

Comment: I think the problem is the argument in replace function. I think we need to add,  `/g` to find all of the `\\n`. So I tried with `return str.replace("\\n/g", "<br />")` but did not work.

Comment: I figured out the solution! `return str.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />")` this worked!